# C# NullReferenceException in Enumerator Type in Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, coroutine

I asked in game development unsuccessfully, because it is happening un Unity3D, but as it's C#, the synthax and the error is the same as C# for programming:

```
public ResultadoDaRequisicaoAoServidor executar()
{
StartCoroutine(MoverPersonagem());
return someThinkOfTypeResultadoDaRequisicaoAoServidor;
}
public IEnumerator MoverPersonagem()
{

yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
//Tried  "yield return null" too
float duracao=2000;
float TempoGasto=0;
while(TempoGasto<duracao)
{
    TempoGasto+=Time.deltaTime;     
    gameObject.transform.position = 
    Vector3.Lerp(posicaoOrigem,posicaoDestino,TempoGasto/duracao);          
}        
}
```

It returns me:

```
NullReferenceException UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine (IEnumerator routine) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineMonoBehaviourBindings.gen.cs:61) Andar2.executar () (at Assets/Scripts/Andar2.cs:38) ComportamentoDoPersonagem+c__Iterator5.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Personagem/ComportamentoDoPersonagem.cs:57) UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
```

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you are suppose to have `yield return new null` inside the while loop. It is a must.While at it, debug your own code. Check if `posicaoOrigem` or `posicaoDestino` is null. `if(posicaoOrigem==null){Debug.Log("posicaoOrigem is null")}` and `if(posicaoDestino==null){Debug.Log("posicaoDestino is null")}`

Comment: @Programmer yes, the 'new null' was wrong, the original code was not like that, I fixed above. The errors happens in the *StartCoroutine(MoverPersonagem());* line.

Comment: So this is fixed?

Comment: I fixed the synthax, problem still remains, it is not posicaoOrigem or posicaoDestino null exeption, I made the test, the error is in the  *StartCoroutine(MoverPersonagem())* line itself.